# Why didn't Hoggle turn into a princess after he is kissed by Sarah?

Tags: plot-explanation, labyrinth

In **Labyrinth**, Jareth warns Hoggle if he was kissed by Sarah then he will turn him into a princess.

In the middle of the the movie Hoggle was **kissed** by Sarah.

[image]

Jareth was watching all the activities in his magical ball.

[image]

Then why didn't Hoggle turn into a princess after he is kissed by Sarah?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, he said he'd turn him into a *prince* - Prince of the Land of Stench.  He was threatening Hoggle and, when Sarah kissed Hoggle, they were sent to the Land of Stench.

Answer (score 2):

Jareth's comment was meant to be ironic and mean; not literal.

A common fairy tail trope is that if a creature is kissed by a princess, then he will turn into a prince. Jareth first says "I'll turn you into a prince" and then pauses, giving Hoggle hope that Jareth will do something nice. Then, he continues on to say "Prince of the Land of Stench"; showing that he didn't really mean an actual prince; but rather that it was a threat.

When Sarah kisses Hoggle, he follows through with his threat and sends them to the Bog of Eternal Stench.